# What is the best way to handle data frame return from R to Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

My requirement needs me to send in a few user selected values from Tableau (through parameters of course) and trigger an R script which creates two CSV files and I need to display these two CSV files on Tableau screen. What are my options?

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Created parameters in Tableau screen and created a Calculated field to call R script with parameters passed on by the user
2. Wrote the CSV files onto hard drive.
3. Refresh the data connection to get updated CSV files onto Tableau.

But the work around I have used (described above) is complicated and isnt easy for a business user. Is there a better way to handle this?